# Как именно происходит вызов системной функции с точки зрения памяти процесса?

Tags: c, winapi, syscall

Мне известно о том, что при распределении виртуальной памяти процесса, некий диапазон адресов отдается на так называемый режим ядра (Kernel mode). Однако что именно располагается в этом диапазоне адресов?! 
Располагается ли там непосредственно некие машинные инструкции кода ядра или же это только память , используемая в режиме пользовательского кода особым образом?

В этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/post/415685/ дана схема взаимодействия программы пользовательского режима и ядра ОС. Там говорится что при системном вызове пользовтельский код записывает данные в некую разделяемую память процесса(это как я понял виртуальное адресное пространство самого пользовательского процесса, верно?). После чего делает вызов к ядру ОС, которое после обработки возвращает данные в пространство пользовательского режима (вирт адресное пространство, как я понял?).

Но я не совсем понял и мне интересно как это все физически происходит в памяти.
Мне представляется следующая схема:
Когда коду моей программы необходимо сделать системный вызов (например загрузить/замапить некий файл, или же вычитать данные из буфера tcp или нечто подобное), она, **во первых** записывает данные запроса в определенную память внутри адресов, зарезервированных для ядра. **во вторых** вызывает некий машинный код, расположенный опять же в диапазоне адресов ядра (и являющийся кодом ядра, т.е некую функцию как точку входа в системный вызов). После этого, **в третьих** Либо же сразу, либо же после того как после некоего прерывания процессора, после того как он начнет обрабатывать код всяких системных планировщиков и менеджеров памяти, т.е перейдет в режим ядра (верно ли я рассуждаю). Системный код найдет информацию об обращении пользовательского процесса к системным ресурсам, обработает это обращение и запишет результат в память таким образом, что при переключение проца на выполнение кода пользовательского режима, код моей программы сможет эти результаты из памяти забрать.

Происходит ли все примерно так или иначе? Может быть все проще и при системном вызове код моей программы просто обращается к неким функциям расположенным в пространстве зарезервированном для ядра? Но если так, то как код программы узнает об адресах системных функций в памяти? Ведь в этом случае для библиотек kernel должны существовать механизмы, отвечающие за то, чтобы линковщик после компиляции распознал экспорт этих функций из этих kernel библиотек, чтобы потом во время загрузки PE файла в память загрузчик мог проставить адреса этих системных функций в моей программе (ну, обычная линковка с++ и т.д)

Буду очень признателен за ответы или ссылки на статьи, раскрывающие эту тему (желательно на русском)
Хочется разобраться в этой всей путанице, возникшей у меня в голове))

Comment: 1) НЕТ. Параметры системного вызова находятся в пространстве пользователя (конечно, регистры пользователя при обработке прерывания (системного вызова)  сохраняются в пространстве ядра). 2) ДА. Вызов производится через синхронное прерывание (обычно для этого есть специальная команда) 3). СРАЗУ

Comment: Нет никаких материалов, где это понятно описано. Желательно статьи размером до 30 страниц, а то времени читать книги особо нет(

Comment: К сожалению, под рукой ничего такого нет. Если в коде разбираетесь, то libc часть можно посмотреть, например, [тут](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch) и повыше по дереву. А системную поискать в коде linux

Answer (score 0):

> Но если так, то как код программы узнает об адресах системных функций
>   в памяти? Ведь в этом случае для библиотек kernel должны существовать
>   механизмы, отвечающие за то, чтобы линковщик после компиляции
>   распознал экспорт этих функций из этих kernel библиотек, чтобы потом
>   во время загрузки PE файла в память загрузчик мог проставить адреса
>   этих системных функций в моей программе (ну, обычная линковка с++ и
>   т.д)

Традиционно системный вызов производится через команду прерывания (не через аппаратное прерывание). Это позволяет приложениям не линковаться с ядром при загрузке в смысле обычной линковки.

Можно-ли приложениям линковаться с ядром при загрузке в смысле обычной линковки? Вопрос интересный. Для этого в системе должна была бы лежать карта загрузки ядра или даже объектник ядра. Причем линковка должна производиться с учетом установленного ОЗУ (размер которого может меняться при эксплуатации системы), а также с учетом того, что логические адреса в нынешних процессорах отражаются на физические адреса через MMU уже в рантайме.

Comment: В традиционной ОС прямой вызов функций ядра из пространства пользователя невозможен, поскольку это *разные* адресные пространства (физических страниц, в которых размещен код ядра попросту нет в карте памяти с которой работает пользовательский процесс).  При прерывании (оно, как вы наверняка знаете,  обрабатывается ядром) текущая карта памяти меняется на карту ядра. В процессе работы ядро может подключать в свое пространство карту памяти любого пользовательского процесса для копирования данных.

Comment: @avp Если бы стояла задача линковаться с ядром при загрузке, то вполне можно было бы сделать аппаратную поддержку этого процесса. Но тогда бы (как минимум) возросла бы уязвимость к хакерским атакам, когда злонамеренный код передает управление напрямую в ядро. Зато уже при загрузке было бы видно, какие системные функции, которые вызываются в приложении, не поддерживаются в данном ядре. Хотя в принципе такую проверку можно провести и сейчас, но не средствами линковщика конечно.

Comment: Это легко можно сделать и без аппаратной поддержки. Впрочем, подобные решения, когда ОС (и только те ее функции, которые нужны приложению) собирается вместе с приложением (например DNS) существуют. Тогда в результате загрузки мы сразу получаем работающее в режиме ядра приложение. Обычно это оформляют как виртуальную машину.